# Avalonia ui extension of the click area by ToggleButton

Tags: c#, avalonia

I've run into a problem. What are the ways in the TreeDataGrid to expand the click area on the ToggleButton in the HierarchicalExpanderColumn to the entire cell?

I tried to shove a button into the Cell and stretch it in width and height, but I did not understand how to connect it with a click on the togglebutton and on the left there is an area not covered by the button

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine the cell template and insert a button into it, then it will stretch over the entire cell

```
<Style Selector="TreeDataGridExpanderCell">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate>
                                            <ToggleButton
                                            
                                                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                          Focusable="True"
                                                          IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                          Background="Transparent"
                                                          IsVisible="True"
                                                      
                                                      >
                                                <ContentControl>
                                                    <Border x:Name="CellBorder"
                                                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                                            CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
                                                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Indent, Converter={StaticResource IndentConverter}}}"
                                                     >
                                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin=" 0 0 0 0">
                                                            <Image Margin="-0 0 4 0"
                                                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                                  Height="20">
                                                                <Image.Source>
                                                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{x:Static vm:FilesPageViewModel.ArrowIconConverter}">
                                                                        <Binding Path="IsDirectory"/>
                                                                        <Binding Path="IsExpanded"/>
                                                                        <Binding Path="HasChildren"/>
                                                                    </MultiBinding>
                                                                </Image.Source>
                                                            </Image>
                                                            <Image Margin="10 0 4 0"
                                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                                   Height="30">
                                                                <Image.Source>
                                                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{x:Static vm:FilesPageViewModel.FileIconConverter}">
                                                                        <Binding Path="IsDirectory"/>
                                                                        <Binding Path="IsExpanded"/>
                                                                    </MultiBinding>
                                                                </Image.Source>
                                                            </Image>
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
    
                                                        </StackPanel>
                                                    </Border>
                                                </ContentControl>
                                                <ToggleButton.Styles>
                                                    <Style Selector="ToggleButton:checked /template/ ContentPresenter">
                                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                                                    </Style>
                                                    <Style Selector="ToggleButton:pointerover /template/ ContentPresenter">
                                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                                                    </Style>
                                                </ToggleButton.Styles>
                                            </ToggleButton>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).